# How to change the background color of Tab widget in Android?

Tags: android

I am using TabWidget. It comes with the default grey background color. Is it possible to change this? If it is then please tell me how can I do this??

Thanks 
Sankar Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=6

Ger

Comment: The blog post linked doesn't actually seem to answer the question asked - it only shows the basics on how to use Tab widgets, and not changing the background color.

Comment: It does. Look at the TabViewConfig object, and more particularly, to its headerResourceId where you define the background